# How can I use std::sort() with std::unique_ptr<[]>?

Tags: c++, std

```
std::unique_ptr<type[]> D{ std::make_unique<type[]>(10'000) };

std::sort(D2[0], D2[10'000], [](auto& a, auto& b)->bool {return a < b; }); //error
```

I use `std::unique_ptr<[]>` to read binary-file.
if I want to sort this data, Am I have to make another vector or something?
I have no idea how to use `sort` func with `unique_ptr<[]>`. Can you tell me the way?

Comment: For "arrays" you need a *pointer* to the first and one-beyond last element.

Comment: And excuse my curiosity, but why a `std::unique_ptr<type[]>` rather than a `std::vector<type>` or possibly `std::array<type, 10'000>`?

Comment: `std::sort(&D2[0], &D2[10'000], ...)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not OP but `std::vector<type>` can be resized and `D` can't. It isn't burdened with the related interface or with tracking size or capacity. `std::array<type,10000>` needs a `constexpr` size but `D` doesn't.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the lambda here, that comparison will be the default.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux More importantly, vectors can be accidentally copied.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `operator[]` triggers an assert for end iterators under some implementations in debug mode. It certainly does in visual studio for `std::vector`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili not for raw arrays that I know of, only for containers

Comment: @AlanBirtles that's right. I just wanted to mention that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, this is unfortunate that the standard does not require this to work.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. don't you mean "requires it to not work"? or does your definition of "work" include undefined behaviour that *currently* does what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pointers as iterators for the sort routine:

```
std::sort(D.get(), D.get() + 10'000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you know that, in C++11 and above, the iterator header provides begin() and end() functions for built in array types that return pointers to the first and one past the end element of the array ?